# How to get search query volume?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am working on a project for a customer and needed search query volume, which is accessible from Seller Central's Brand Analytics tab named "Search Query Performance." I also need the ASIN view, which provides search query volume for each keyword for the ASIN you search for. I tried to obtain the data from the SP API, but the most relevant result I found was "GET_BRAND_ANALYTICS_SEARCH_TERMS_REPORT," which seems random and does not exactly provide the same data. While searching, I came across the stoke.com website, which provided the information I wanted. However, I couldn't figure out how they obtain the data and why they have access to Seller Central in addition to the SP API and Amazon Ads API access. I was hoping someone could assist me with this.

Thank you.